# PHP cURL can not connect to remote server

Tags: php, curl

It works with my localhost, works well when I put this php file on other Host but whenever I put this php file in my BlueHost server this code does not work, it returns HTTP code 0. I have contacted with BlueHost customer service they said they opened every port they dont know what is wrong. So I checked the php.ini file, there I enabled cURL dll but still not working.

On the other hand, I have also contacted the server which I am hitting with cURL, they said its their test server so they are not restricting any IP.

```
<?php
$plazaCode = isset($_GET['plazaCode']) ? $_GET['plazaCode'] : 3413921;
$productCode = isset($_GET['productCode']) ? $_GET['productCode'] : 18044;
$requestUrl = "http://103.243.142.55:8080/eComm/OnlineSale/currentStock?plazaCode=$plazaCode&productCode=$productCode";  

$content = get_data($requestUrl);
echo $content;

function get_data($url) {
    try{
        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($ch === FALSE){
            throw new Exception('failed to initialize cURL variable');}
        $timeout = 60;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 0);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        print curl_error($ch);
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'input url = '.$url;
        echo '<br>';
        foreach(curl_getinfo($ch) as $key=>$value){
            if($key=='http_code')
                echo 'response '.$key.' = '.$value.'<br/>';
        }
        //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        trigger_error(sprintf(
            'cURL failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
            E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I have tested your code in localhost and it's working. Can you please comment out `if ($ch === FALSE){ throw new Exception('failed to initialize cURL variable');}` and post here the output of `print curl_error($ch);` if it gets there? if it doesn't execute until there, also post your `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: I have edited like you said. curl_error() shows `connect() timed out!`. I am giving you a link where you can see the phpinfo()..  http://www.arpondigital.com/walton/phpinfo.php  also see this
http://arpondigital.com/walton/testServer.php

Comment: is it a shared hosting or a private one? Can you run `curl -Is http://www.google.com | head -n 1` from terminal? to see if curl can actually run.

Comment: no man its a shared hosting and i cant access the terminal

Comment: using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and choosing any stream handler but curl might be your solution. Sorry for not being able to help you out more, as I'm out of time now. [check here](https://gist.github.com/nacholibre/58072687059e4e386c8a) for an example.

Comment: @Cemal alright I managed to connect the terminal with PuTTY and yes it shows HTTP 200 for google.com which means cURL is running. So?

Comment: can you comment out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);` or set `$timeout = 0;` and retry. It might be a bug related to your libcurl version